# Linux boot fails after install

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, boot, gnome

I got an hp pavilion 15 e070sl laptop, bought a week ago and i wanted to install ubuntu alongside windows, (then the installer erased the whole HDD for a bug, but that's another story)

The fact is, once disabled fastboot/secureboot/everything needed i installed ubuntu linux with 13.04, allok but wifi wasn't working.

I switched to a newer version:13.10, during the install process wifi is detected and worked good.

But boot didn't work(Freeze on Gnome logo), using livecd in try mode also didn't work.
How to get errors prompted so i can understand what's not working?

Somebody else had the same problem?